# How to refresh RecyclerView on android studio after adding a new data on API?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have made an android studio app and I have a remote server that has RestFul API. I have a RecyclerView which shows all rows from a table. When I make a post request, the post request is successful and sends back the newly added row as a JsonObject as a response. My question is how should I show the new data on my recycler view? Should I just do a refresh so that I can get the whole list from the server with an api call? This seems to me like waste of resources since there is a new call, new list, etc. Or should I just update the RecyclerView with the response data of the newly added object without making an api call? This consumes less resources but I am not getting the most recent data from the server which could be a problem if there are many simultaneous users interacting with the same database?

Answer (score 0):

You can call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter if you have an update